# Data extraction of text of a specific class

Tags: classification, nlp, information-extraction

I have a set of documents for which I have to extract (or identify the location of) text of a particular class.  So, the class may be "conversations about dogs".  I can train a BERT model (or similar) to recognize if a given string of text is about dogs or not.  However, the class text can be of different lengths.  The document text I need to identify could be 5 words long, or 500 words long.  So the issue is, how much text from a document do I need to extract in order to present to the BERT model to let it classify if the text is of the class I am looking for?  Right now, I am pulling one sentence at a time and checking that.  But, sometimes, an individual sentence isn't enough context.  But I don't want to grab 1,2,3,4,N groups of sentences and try them all.  That feels wrong.

Ideally, I could run a model on all the text (like a page) and it would just return the text that is of the class I'm looking for (if it exists).

What is the best approach in this case?